# Op amp current regulator

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting

This is probably a marginal mistake.

This circuit, a current regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmIZi0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Works fine on simulation.

However, it does not once built. I built it twice, once on a PCB once on a breadboard, using different components, and both behave the same.

The OA2 output is either at High or Low, depending on the V1 but is not regulating anything.

I also observe some kind of schmitt trigger behavior, current is 0 and V1 is 0, then slowly increase the voltage, it suddenly switch to the max output. Then I have to reduce V1 to almost 0 to stop conducting.

There is no oscillation or anything like this. it's either fully on / off instead of regulating.

At this point I do not believe it's a mistake on the build.

---

- Opamp are single rail supplied at 10V.
- V1 is 0-1V to control 0-1A.
- I tried with [BA2902](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/amp_linear/opamp/ba10358-e.pdf) and [OPA227](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos110b/sbos110b.pdf)

Comment: It looks unnecessarily complicated. The node above \$R_7\$ *should* replace where \$R_2\$ goes. Meaning that \$R_2+R_5+R_6+R_3+R_4+OA_1\$ = unnecessary. - This is a comment, not an answer, because I'd like to hear *why* you've gone with this design, which I might have missed.

Comment: What op amps? What supply voltage?

Comment: It is actually a current bypass, in some situation, R7 might not be directly tied to the ground, so OA1 is there as a differential comparator. @HarrySvensson

Comment: @MattYoung single rail 3-30V opamp, supplied 10V. V1 is 0-1V.

Comment: "single rail 3-30V opamp" is not enough information. What is the actual part?

Comment: I tried with BA2902 and OPA227 @MattYoung

Comment: Ah, okay, so \$R_7\$ could be anywhere else.. even on the high side. -As you will notice, dealing with something as simple as differential amplification, requires proper calibration. I mean proper proper. - The easiest way of measuring current is to just keep \$R_7\$ at ground all the time and do what I said in my first comment. *That way* you won't have to deal with matching the other resistors to within 0.1% or whatever precision you require. - An instrumentation amplifier would solve your differential amplification problem, but an actual analog ic current meter would be best. Like INA213.

Comment: Perusing the OPA227 datasheet reveals that the common mode range does not include v- or v+. It looks like you are using a single supply but your op-amps are not rated for rail-to-rail inputs. The inputs must be at least 2 volts from the rails for it to work.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I agree, but I'm limited by design constrain and cost. Calibration is not an issue however.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri I thought about it and for test I used a 10ohm resistor to have a 500mV input on the op-amp, but the behavior was the same. Perhaps this wouldn't be enough. I will try to test it with a rail to rail.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri It does work with the OPA227 and negative supply rail (I thought it was a single rail). So you are probably right.

Comment: The common mode voltage range of OPA227 seems to be from V-+2 to V+-2. 500 mV is nowhere near that range. You could use 3-4 diode drops between R7 and ground, or an adjustable Vbe multiplier, to raise the op amp inputs above ground. OA2 also doesn't have inputs within its allowed range (and the OA1 output has the same problem). Increasing the set voltage and the R7 resistance would correct that.

Comment: My first impression of this circuit is to worry about oscillation and the need for a gate drive that is higher than your rails. (I know you say there is no oscillation in the practical build.) But, if you set \$R_1=10\:\Omega\$ then a suitably dissipating NPN BJT would eliminate much of those worries. I'm curious if you might try one in your practical circuit to see how it performs. If it works better, that tells you something. Any chance you could attempt it? (Obviously, keep your load's required voltage drop well within range of your supply, when testing.)

Comment: @jonk The oscillation is fixed by a cap on the mosfet gate. I didn't go for the BJT for 2 reasons, one you need significantly higher gate current, the second is due to design need, current cannot be "lost" or "added" on the whole current path. I though agree with you a BJT will probably oscillate less and was the topic of another of my question on the electronic stackexchange.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri you were right, I've made a new pcb and changed the amp to rail to rail and it works, you may post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing the OPA227 datasheet reveals that the common mode range does not include v- or v+.

It looks like you are using a single supply but your op-amps are not rated for rail-to-rail inputs. The inputs must be at least 2 volts from the rails for it to work.

Exceeding the allowed common mode range will produce all manner of strange results like the ones you have observed.

There are 2 possible ways out.

1. Use an op-amp with rail-to-rail i/o
2. Add a negative power supply rail below ground to move ground into the acceptable common mode range.